# Is there any Font ligature with CamelCase separator

Tags: fonts, camelcasing, ligature

I have a problem, that I cannot read properly, even with glasses, if the letters are small and condensed I have a hard time to figure out the word. And also I am a web Designer, often use React.js. and you could not imagine what its like for me to use CamelCase for every functions.

Recently I came to know about **Font Ligatures**. So I am thinking if by any chance there is some font with ligatures that puts a bit space between the CamelCase letters. You might say I can zoom in, yes I can, but if I do so I cannot see much of the code I needed.

It may sound stupid to you but this problem is effecting my job.

I do not know if any one has this problem. Please let me know any of such font. I am building my custom ligatures anyways

Comment: In principle, it would be possible for a font to add some visual space between letters when ligatures are activated, but adding space is not a ligature, so it's unlikely that any font would do that. Are you looking for more space between all letters? Only in camel cased words, or all text?

Comment: Yes ! I meant the visual space in between letters only for camel case

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1722193/446855 , a thought on vscode API